# How to deal with programmers who think there is “one true way” to write software?

Tags: communication, colleagues, psychology

I've been coding for iOS for years now, and I'm continually finding that I encounter programmers who believe there is one true way to write software for iOS; typically these are guys who have very little experience, and are just imitating what they think Apple does or wants. but I've spoken extensively with people who work at Apple and they don't do things in this "one true way" themselves, nor do they recommend it. How do I best deal with these highly opinionated programmers, who insist on very strict variable naming conventions, very strict spacing, but also program structures that would not necessarily pass muster in a programming class. I feel very much like I joined a cult and I'm the only person in it who has free will. They think very highly of themselves (geeks are known for their hubris)  but they are incapable of arguing their case.

Unimaginative conformist behavior is not a sign of intelligence.

If an engineer deserves any respect, is because he is able to argue his case.  Mindlessly demanding conformity is the opposite of arguing your case. It is like  these people are coddled children, and they can't imagine anyone questioning their demands.

either that, or fundamentalist thinking has spread into the programming profession.

Comment: What you describe doesn't sound like cargo cult programming. It sounds like these developers follow a single set of coding conventions which is *basic common sense*.

Comment: They appear to have a established a very strict coding standard, which is a best practice among professional software teams. Can you provide more examples of why their "one true way" is bad?

Comment: Please remember to keep your comments polite and professional and in line with the [Be Nice](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Comment: @JaneS  are people who have 8000 points penalized when they are not nice?

Comment: @Doeyd Comments that are not appropriate are deleted, regardless of whoever made them.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a place for ranting about your coworkers and telling us how stupid they are and how much better you are than them. If you treat them like you are treating this question it is no wonder you have problems dealing with them. There is good guidance in the [help center](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about making this question a better fit. Please take some time to read that as well as the Be Nice policy Jane mentioned above.

Comment: Some people perhaps think one particular way is the best way because they have been using it for so long that it's easily readable to them. When if they'd used another standard they would think the same of the other. That's something that they might not be able to put into words easily, because to them it's just 'right' and they think everyone should understand because it's self-evident (to them). Alternatively they might not want to voice a reason like "Otherwise the boss will make us re-write the whole thing again because he's like that". Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The only red flag is the phrase ".. and they are incapable of arguing their case". While it is absolutely basic common sense to follow a set of coding conventions, everyone should be able to explain the reasoning behind the decisions (apart from truly simple stuff where it doesn't matter at all what the convention is as long as everyone follows it - like tabs/spaces or bracket style)

Comment: "who insist on very strict variable naming conventions, very strict spacing, and so on" - That sounds like a good group of people to work with to be honest. Having readable code is very important and I don't think it is at all unreasonable to not want bloated code that nobody can read down the line. As Brian Kernighan said, "Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?"

Comment: @Brandin this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 4):

I find much the same thing since I work with different groups, each of which may have their own similar but different conventions. There probably is NO true way per se. But it's best practice to follow the conventions of the particular group your working with. Not argue about them.

How to deal with it is keep an open mind and ignore anyone ranting too much about a certain way of coding. Doing things your own way just gets you branded as an amateur and a cowboy which you obviously are not.

What you may think is a cooler and more efficient way of coding might be difficult for others to read quickly which is a major drawback in groups. As a sometimes employer of consultants, if one of my people sent me code that looked messy I'd send it back to them and tell them to clean up their gibberish before giving it to me.

Comment: what I'm saying is that THEY are not keeping an open mind at all. they are egotistical, small minded, immature and tyrannical. they cannot  form a coherent argument for why they chose these particular ways of doing things, because in the end they are  unimaginative conformists,  acting like they are special snowflakes who have to be listened to.  I expect they were coddled by their parents.

Comment: Perhaps you're correct, but it's a moot point in my opinion. In my experience it's non productive to let the pettiness or perceived pettiness of others impact on your own professionalism. Conforming to standards is the norm for professionals, homogeneity or an approximation of it smooths many paths and makes things easier for the majority.

Comment: as for consultants, my experience is that full timers  often do worse work  then some consultants, because full timers are more often than not  complacent. and many are lazy.

Comment: I agree, consultants tend to be more pedantic and less lazy, unfortunately there IS a lot of cowboys out there and you never know until you receive their work :( I don't pay until I have what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Do you work with them? Because you said you "continually encounter programmers...".

If you do, well, you will have to adapt your code to their practices. Because, congratulations!, for once, you found a group of programmers that actually follow industry standards. They already decided to use a methodology that works for them and they are happy with it. Sure, everything can be improved (especially if they are *my* improvements ;) ), but then work would never get done.

As a teacher once said to me: use whatever standard you want, but follow it. That's why it's called a standard.

Comment: There is more than one way to skin a cat.  It is erroneous to say everybody on the project needs to be using the same style.  if an engineer deserves any respect, is because he is able to argue his case.  mindlessly demanding conformity is the opposite of arguing your case.

Comment: There are many places in software development where you can exercise your creativity.  Coding style is not one of them.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty normal in the industry for a team to use the same standards. Otherwise it's just confusing. Generally an organisation defines what the standards are. If you think you have a case to make against those standards, you should definitely bring it to your manager, but until then, use whatever standards are consistent.

Comment: standards are not the only issue though.  for instance when it comes to IOS programming, people want to use Apple-patented technologies. but there is no good arguable case for that other than blind conformity.